# Different approach of using IN clause with MySql

Tags: mysql

I found 2 approach of using IN clause in MySQL:

Version 1:

```
SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE column_name IN (val1,val2,...)
```

Version 2:

```
SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE val1 IN (column_name)
```

As you can see here the position of the column_name and values are interchanged.

I did not succeed in using this second version!
But I found the way to get the proper results with this second approach, and I'd like to share it with you:

```
SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE FIND_IN_SET(val1, column_name) > 0
```

Comment: You are apparently storing comma-delimited values in a single column.  A simple comment is too short to explain why this is a bad idea.  You need to learn about junction tables, if you are going to use databases effectively.

Comment: I am not the owner of this databases and cannot change it. The purpose of my question is to find the better way to query in such situation.

Comment: This doesn't seem to be a question?

Comment: So you have found `FIND_IN_SET()` function for comma separated values? Congrats! :)